# Custom network interface with packet send and receive functions in user space

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ip, c

Is it possible to implement a custom network interface in user space on a Linux platform? The netif must transmit packets on an unusual physical link which is best accessed in user space.

The send and receive functions must work on the IP level and ARP should not be attempted by Linux as the link is not Ethernet and has its own method of address resolution.

How to go about such a task, in C for example? Any example code to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and a lot of software does that; basically, all userland VPN implementations!

The trick here is to ask the kernel to make a TUN or TAP device, and attach your software to it.

- Use TAP for software implementation on the Ethernet layer,
- Use TUN for software implementation on the IP layer.

There's a lot of examples and tutorials, here's what the wikipedia article on [TUN/TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) should link to: [Kernel documentation on tuntap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt); here's a stackoverflow [answer on how to use the tun driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735842/4433386)